# Existence of a solution of a nonlinear ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have to show, that the nonlinear ODE
$$u'(t)-2u''(t) u(t)=-1,\quad u(0)=1,\,u'(0)=0$$
has a unique solution $v(t)\in C^2(0,T)$ on any Interval $[0,T]$, $T>0$ and that 
$$\max_{0\leq t\leq T}(v(t))=v(T).$$
I'm not very familiar with nonlinear ODEs and since this is from the first sheet out of our partial differential euqations course, I think there must be a trick which I don't see.

I already looked at the solution using Mathematica, but the explicit one looks very complicated and I don't think, that we are wanted to find it.